# Warning in Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execution-plan

I have a `T-SQL` query with four inner joins, I executed the query in `SSMS` with `Actual Execution Plan` selected. When I review the generated plan I saw the warning icon on `Sort` operator. 
What is the reason for this warning in `Sort` operator?

The Query Plan URL: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJULL9H4N

I provided the screen shot of Execution Plan.
[image]

The Warning: 
[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/query-plan-warnings/ What tooltip says when you click over the sort operator?

Comment: Cardinality estimation for the second partecipant in your last join was wrong, server underestimated it, as the result merge join was chosen where hash is more appropriate. Underestimation caused memory grant to be lower and your Sort was spilled into tempdb

Comment: To fix the issue you can save the join result into a temporary table before joining it to dbo.Student. This will help SQL Server to have the exact estimation of the second partecipant of your last join

Comment: @sepupic, maybe there is not enough memory to be granted instead of the wrong estimation

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin When you see the actual number of rows in red be sure it differs from estimated number of rows

Comment: @Asrar Ahmad Ehsan Please paste the plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and update your question with the link to your pasted plan

Comment: @sepupic, thanks, I was not aware of it. Nevertheless a lack of memory can be the case. But I guess, you must be right about the wrong estimation.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the reason for this warning in Sort operator?

You can see the warning description in properties of the element. I'm sure you will see information like below:

> Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution.....

It means that memory which was granted for the query turned out to be less than it needed. Two possible reasons for that:

1. Wrong cardinality estimation so the query asked for the less memory grant than it really needed
2. Lack of memory so the query asked enough memory but got less

Detailed information about memory grant can be found in the properties window of `SELECT`operation from your query plan.

Answer (score 1):

I am not writing a complete new answer. Most of it is covered between the comments and answer by Denis.

Two possible reason mentioned.  `Wrong cardinality estimation` and `Lack of memory`.  I will explain how you can rule out `Lack of Memory`.

MaxQueryMemory under MemoryGrantInfo (once you right click the leftmost select node): Maximum amount of memory available for individual query grant in KB, if the query requires memory to run.

[image]

So if the MaxQueryMemory is larger than requested memory it is a good indication that sort warning is NOT due lack memory, it is rather due bad cardinality estimation.

A worth reading about [Understanding SQL server memory grant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2010/02/16/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/)

Ref:

- [2017 Schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/sql2017/showplanxml.xsd)
- [Update to expose maximum memory enabled for a single query in Showplan XML in SQL Server 2014 or 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3170112/update-to-expose-maximum-memory-enabled-for-a-single-query-in-showplan)